# Change Speed of a Player depending on screensize

Tags: java, android, bitmap, sprite

So I have made a game in eclipse with java for android where a player dodges obstacles that are falling from above  and when i tested it on different screen sizes ( Not emulator. real phones! Used a galaxy s4( Bigger screen) and htc(smaller screen)) the speed of the player was different. At the htc the speed was normal but on the galaxy s4 the player was too slow. Its because of the resolution and size differences and now i am just asking for a example of java code how to detect these differences and actually change the speed of the player.I didnt try anything yet except with if statements like:

```
if (myView.getWidth() < 500) 
{
xSpeed = 5;
}
```

but didnt really work well.   If you guys need any more information consider asking please. Im thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a suggestion which I actually used in my own game because I faced this same issue. The suggestion is: **make everything relative** i.e. your displacement, velocities, accelerations etc.

For instance if you need to make the speed relative do something like this:

```
xSpeed = SCREEN_WIDTH/20;
```

Now if you had a screen width of `200 pixels` on one phone, `400 pixels` on other and `800 pixels` on yet another, your speed will change relatively, being `10, 20, 40 pixels` respectively. I hope you understand and please provide code if you require further assistance.